# Which jade.vim plugin to use?

Tags: vim, pug, vim-plugin

Github has modules produced by
[statianzo](https://github.com/statianzo/vim-jade),
[vim-scripts](https://github.com/vim-scripts/jade.vim), and
[digitaltoad](https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-jade).
None of the three are related by forking

And google finds this:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3192

Which one is best?

---

Copying from below (vote those guys up if you find their info useful):

[vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3192) == [vim-scripts](https://github.com/vim-scripts/jade.vim) - this is the original module

... after some edits and extensions (more syntax highlighting cases from what I can tell)  the code evolves into ...

[digitaltoad](https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-jade) - most popular

[statianzo](https://github.com/statianzo/vim-jade) - similar looking features to digitaltoad, fewer followers

Right now, I'm going with the digitaltoad module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vim-scripts repos on GitHub are just git mirrors of the plugins on vim.org.  It even says this in the README for that repo on GitHub, and points to the script on vim.org.  That takes care of two of your links.

It appears the digitaltoad repo appears as though it was based on the package on vim.org at some point as some of the files attribute the maintainer to be the same person.  That repo may have since diverged from the one on vim.org.

The stantianzo repo looks like it's possibly a little different than either of the others.

My advice is to just try them out and use the one that you find works best for you.

Answer (score 5):

The digitaltoad repo has the most recent commits, so I'd probably plump for that one.  Recent commits doesn't *necessarily* mean better/more stable, but at least you know someone is actively working on it.

Comment: the digitaltoad module seems like it handles more syntax highlighting cases.  seems like it was an extension of the vim.org scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried both using vundle to install and digitaltoad's 'just worked', whereas statianzo's didn't auto indent. As always, ymmv.